# How to keep everything in place on smaller screens and allow horizontal scrolling?

Tags: html, css

I don't want to resize or scale anything, I just want the content to stay in the same position, at the same size and allow horizontal scrolling on smaller screens. Horizontal scrolling is allowed by default, but everything just gets out of place. I'm a newbie, but I still think there's a simple solution to this. I used pixels to position all my elements, maybe I should've used percentages instead? Someone enlighten me, please!

Comment: no code ? no chocolate ! are we supposed to guess your structure and layout methods you used ?

Comment: Without more context on what you currently have, any answers you get won't be very useful to you, since you'll have to adapt it to varying degrees to suit your needs -- **more work for you** (indeed some answers may even completely miss the mark). If you post a relevant snippet of your current code, then you will get lots of relevant, accurate and useful answers. The current question asks for a lot from answerers in that we have to play the guessing game with what you want -- **more work for us**.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use something like:

```
.scrolls {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 80px;
    white-space:nowrap
}
```

You can find more information in [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_overflow-x).

Example:

```css
div.ex1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 50px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<h1>The overflow-x Property</h1>

<h2>overflow-x: scroll:</h2>
<div class="ex1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit...</div>

</body>
</html>
```